# Detecting tab space and next-lime markup symbols in text files

Tags: java, parsing

I need to parse a raw text file having a item for each line, and tab-delimited fields.

How can I detect a tab space and next-line markup symbols from a plain text document ? I was thinking to use Java APIs for it... but if you know any faster language and easy to use) for text parsing please let me know

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String str = "Hello\tworld\nHello Universe";
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str.contains("\t"));
System.out.println(str.indexOf("\t"));
System.out.println(str.contains("\n"));
System.out.println(str.indexOf("\n"));
```

**Output:**

```
Hello        world
Hello Universe
true
5
true
11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 try 
 {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
     String strLine = "";
      while (br.readLine() != null) 
      {
        strLine =br.readLine();
        Scanner str = new Scanner(strLine);
        str.useDelimiter("\t");
        while(str.hasNextToken)
        {
        }
      }
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
```

Comment: @Patrict instead of scanner ,we can also use split("\t")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Guava librairy from Google
Have a look to the [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) and [Guava's slides](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFMQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fguava-libraries.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FGuava_for_Netflix_.pdf&rct=j&q=guava%20slides&ei=DeJfTYHEHtOq8AO287Ra&usg=AFQjCNFK8gv5ud8PVsQ-0ESmwSgIP8rkDQ&sig2=5HMzvOuxY4vZoh_6vus5sQ&cad=rja)

This is an exemple :

```
@Test
public void testGuavaMatcher(){

    String str = "Hello\tworld\nHello Universe";        

    CharMatcher tabMatcher = CharMatcher.is('\t');
    CharMatcher newLineMatcher = CharMatcher.is('\n');

    assertThat(tabMatcher.indexIn(str), is(5));
    assertThat(tabMatcher.matchesAnyOf(str), is(true));
    assertThat(newLineMatcher.indexIn(str), is(11));
    assertThat(newLineMatcher.matchesAnyOf(str), is(true));

    CharMatcher tabAndNewLineMatcher = tabMatcher.or(newLineMatcher);

    assertThat(tabAndNewLineMatcher.removeFrom(str), is("HelloworldHello Universe"));
}
```

You can also have a look to the CharMatcher.BREAKING_WHITESPACE constant.

Comment: That is a complicated way to do what can be achieved in a handful of lines of J2SE!  See Jigar Joshi's code.

Answer (score 0):

Text files do not have 'mark up' as such.  Get each line using BufferedReader.readLine().  Tabs can be found by searching the lines for "\t".